# Trying to install SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows

On a Wndows Server 2008 R2 64 bits, I installed Visual Studio 2010 Express, which installed a SQL Server 2008 Express:

[image: start menu with SSMS]

Trying to install a SQL Server Management Studio, first I'm required to install Service Pack 1. But when trying to do so, I got the following error:

> There are validation errors on this page. Click OK to close this dialog box. Review errors at the bottom Setup page, then provide valid parameters or click Help for more information.

As shown in this image:

[image: installer error message]

Then I uninstalled all SQL Server 2008 components from my server and tried to install Full SQL Server from [this Microsoft download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1279).

(when installing, I would select Express Edition)

No luck, when trying to run setup.exe I get the following errors:

> This program has known compatability issues.

[image: installer error messages]

Then I click n "Check for solutions online" button, but then I get other errors:

> Your version of SQL Server 2008 isn't compatible with this version of Windows.

[image: error explanation]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install SQL Server 2008 first, then *before running or rebooting* install SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1.

You are attempting to install the service pack files first, without an existing base installation of SQL Server 2008.  Since the Service Pack 1 package does not contain a full installation of SQL Server, you must have already installed the non-service-pack version.  The other option would be to create a slip-streamed version of SQL Server 2008 setup by, essentially, combining the Service Pack 1 with the original version on DVD - then installing directly from that.  Check https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22sql+server%22+slipstream+setup for more info.

Don't click "Check for solutions online", click "Run Program" instead.  After that completes, install Service Pack 1.